# Checking if an element is present in protractor-cucumber-framework

Tags: protractor, cucumber, chai

I am having an e2e testing pack with protractor-cucumber-framework and Chai for asserting.

I have a Feature file with a data table as below.

```
Scenario: Menu Validation
        Given I am on the home page
        When I do Hover over the menu item I should have the menu dropdown
            |menu1                    |
            |menu2                    |
            |menu3                    |
```

I have the step definition as below.

```
When(/^I do Hover over the menu item I should have the menu dropdown/, (dataTable) => {
    let rootMenu : Array<string> = Array.from( dataTable.rawTable )
    rootMenu.forEach((ele) => {
        console.log(ele[0]);
        element(by.id(ele[0])).isPresent().then(function(present) { 
            expect(present).to.equal(true);
         });
    });
});
```

Even if the menu element ID is not present this test step never fail, I checked further the `expect(present).to.equal(true);` never get executed. I am not sure what I am missing.

Comment: there are many things I don't understand why you do them this way... for example why you do `forEach` of the `rootMenu` but then you say `ele[0]` like if the rootMenu was an array of arrays

Comment: Yes, I have cucumber feature file which has a data table, The data table is an array of array. So rootMenu have data from the feature file like this [[menu1],[menu2],[menu3]]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you try this instead

```
When(/^I do Hover over the menu item I should have the menu dropdown/, async (dataTable) => {
    let rootMenu : Array<string> = Array.from( dataTable.rawTable )
    for (let i; i < rootMenu.length; i++) {
        let ele = = rootMenu[i];
        console.log(ele[0]);
        expect(await element(by.id(ele[0])).isPresent()).to.equal(true);
    }
})
```

Comment: This works, but i am just interested in why the logic did not work in foreach!!

Comment: foreach just fires off the commands for each element, this is why it has a side effect when running async code inside (the queue just breaks). Please accept the answer if helped you

Comment: and in future, I recommend you to stay away from `.then`, better use `async/await`